# How to implement this nested linked_to_function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, partial-views, link-to, rjs

In my view I want the user to be able to browse a catalog of products. The hierarchy is as following:

```
Category
  Product
    AdditionalInfoForm
```

In my main view I render a partial for the categories:

```
#opContent
  = render :partial => 'op_main_categories'
```

The op_main_categories partial is defined as following:

```
- @controller.getPortalCategories.each do |c|
  = link_to_function "#{c.name}", :class => 'opCategoryHeaderText' do |page| 
    - partial = escape_javascript(render :partial => 'op_secondary_categories', :locals => { :c => c })
    - page << "$('opContent').update(\"#{partial}\")"
```

When the user clicks a link in the above partial, the products are rendered by means of the op_secondary_categories partial:

```
 - @controller.getPortalProductsForCategory(c).each do |p|
   = link_to_function "#{p.name}", :class => 'opCategoryHeaderText' do |page| 
     - partial = escape_javascript(render :partial => 'op_did_line', :locals => { :p => p })
     - page << "$('opContent').update(\"#{partial}\")"
```

op_did_line is plain text for now:

```
%p Yes, this is form! Hello?
```

This setup will generate the following link (for one category):

```
<a class="opCategoryHeaderText" onclick="$('opContent').update("<a class=\"opCategoryHeaderText\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"$(\'opContent\').update("<p>Yes, this is form! Hello?</p>\n"); return false;\">IPSDN + PVC 3yr<\/a>\n<a class=\"opCategoryHeaderText\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"$(\'opContent\').update("<p>Yes, this is form! Hello?</p>\n"); return false;\">PVC<\/a>\n"); return false;" href="#">PVC</a>
```

Adding the second tier of link_to_function breaks all of the code. I am no longer able to browse the hierarchy. When there is only one link_to_function present, I can browse.

This project is still using Rails 2.3. What is a better way to implement this?

Comment: Is that a cut and paste of actual code? Because I see syntax errors. Posting the actual code would help. As well as posting the error your getting.

Comment: `.replaceWidth()` is not a PrototypeJS method - it should be `.replace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved using the answer in [page.insert_html does not insert html with link_to_function (rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194576/page-insert-html-does-not-insert-html-with-link-to-function-rails?rq=1) by "Jose"

The code provided in the answer was put in rails/lib/rails_ext.rb